# How to create identity matrix with numpy with a specific value K at the diagonal

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I would like the array to be like this:

```
 array([[K., 0., 0., 0.],
           [0., K., 0., 0.],
           [0., 0., K., 0.],
           [0., 0., 0., K.]])
```

Answer (score 5):

Addition to liliscent answer.

If you want to have different elements at digonal you can
create a list of your diagonal elements.

```
x= [2,3,4]
```

and use `np.diag()`

```
print(np.diag(x))
```

output:

```
array([[2, 0, 0],
       [0, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 4]])
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [numpy.identity()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.identity.html):

```
K*np.identity(4)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one way:

```
K * np.eye(4)
```

`np.eye` has a few more (possibly unwanted) features versus `np.identity` since it allows you to set unequal rows / columns, and change index of the diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking of it this way.

```
print(np.full((4,4), K) * np.identity(4))
```

but I will go with Liliscent's answer